# Java Copy Constructor is not working as expected

Tags: java, copy-constructor

I am learning Java and recently gone through Copy Constructor tutorial. I tried to write Copy Constructor code however it gives unexpected output.

Question is :

Why is the first output showing `0` and `null` values?

Here is the object with the Copy Constructor:

```
class student6 {

    int id;
    String name;
    int i;
    String n;

    student6(int a, String b) {
        id = a;
        name = b;
    }

    student6(student6 s) {
        i = s.id;
        n = s.name;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(i + "..." + n);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        student6 s1 = new student6(11, "Suresh");
        student6 s2 = new student6(s1);

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}
```

Output

> `0...null`
>
> `11...Suresh`

Comment: Why do you have the `i` and `n` fields at all? What did you expect to do with them?

Comment: FYI, there is no "copy constructor" in Java.  In C++, a copy constructor has a specific arg signature that is recognized as special by the compiler.  The compiler emits _implicit_ calls to the copy constructor in certain situations (e.g., when passing an object in to a function by value)  Nothing like that happens in Java because a Java variable can never hold an object:  `Foo a;` always is a _reference_ to an object wherever you see it.  The constructor that you wrote may _work_ like a C++ copy constructor, but the Java compiler does not treat it any differently from any other constructor.

Comment: Thanks @jameslarge. Yes, that's correct. C++ have copy constructor but Java don't have. Here, I am only 'trying to' get copy constructor kind of response from this program.

Comment: @JonSkeet:- I am trying to get id and name values (which are set by  student6 s1 = new student6(11, "Suresh");) in i and n fields.

Comment: @Aaditya: But why? Why do you have four fields? I can understand a student having a name and an id, but what are the other two fields meant to represent? Do you really want four pieces of state per student? Normally constructors informally referred to as copy constructors copy fields from one instance to another, but copying to the *same* field as they're copying from.

Comment: @JonSkeet ;- I am just trying to get values in `i` and `n` from `s1`. Well, I got the point here, it's because when `s1` initialized and values are passed to `id` and `name` but in `display()`, initially `i` and `n` are displayed (while `i` and `n` value didn't initialize at this moment) and that causing a blank output. So finally conclusion is :- when all 4 variable are 'static' then only same output will be displayed.

Comment: @Aaditya: Well that's just a matter of how static fields behave - and it would be very odd to modify those in a constructor like this. Fundamentally your question was never clear about what you were trying to achieve... you *are* printing out the `i` and `n` field values within `display()`, but it's unclear why you'd ever expect the first line of the output to be anything else, when you haven't set those fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet:- Yes, I am very new to java and don't know much about basic programming rules when it comes to Constructor.

Comment: Well this isn't really about constructors - it's more about fields in general.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change you copy constructor logic from

```
student6(student6 s)
{
i=s.id;
n=s.name;
}
```

to

```
student6(student6 s)
 {
    id=s.id;
    name=s.name;
 }
```

In your display method you are printing `id` and `name`. So you have to initialize them only to see the result.

And please follow **[`Java naming conventions`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)**. Class names starts with Capital letter. `student6` should be `Student6`

P.S : Thanks for printing my name ;)

Comment: @Suresh, I agree by the logic and modified code you have provided. It works as expected. I am just wondering why 'i' and 'n' can't have same values (when values are assigned by constructor) as like `id` and `name`.

Comment: @Aaditya See, they got assigned. But you are not printing them in your display methods. You are assigning to the variables `i` and `n` and printing `id` and `name`

Comment: @Suresh:- Got the answer, only making all the variable as static will work to get expected output:-

    static int id;
    static String name;
    static int i;
    static String n;
so all the values will sustain and output will be as expected.

Comment: No you are doing wrong. Instances should not mix with static.

Comment: @Suresh :- You are right when it comes to follow the programming rules however, I am getting the expected results with static. There was only issue when new variable gets initialized it's not keeping the old ones value (i.e. `id` & `name` ) and static helped in overcome this issue.

Comment: @Aaditya would you mind updating your question with the use case for the `student6` object with the static fields that demonstrates the expected functionality? I suspect that there is something very wrong here and it may be in your best interest to find this out now, rather than in an assignment where it could impact your grade, or (god forbid) much worse in actual code in a production application.

Answer (score 2):

`s1` only initialize `int id;` and `String name;`: this line

```
student6 s1 = new student6(11, "Suresh");
```

calls the first constructor

```
student6(int a, String b) {
    id = a;
    name = b;
}
```

So, calling

```
System.out.println(i + "..." + n);
```

will print default values for `i` and `n`

Answer (score 1):

In the first constructor you are setting the fields `id` and `name` and the second constructor sets the fields `i` and `n`.

When you print both times you print the values of `i` and `n` which are not set for the first object, so they are `0` and `null` respectively.

Here is a modification that results in the output I believe you are expecting.

```
class student6 {

    int id;
    String name;

    student6(int a, String b) {
        id = a;
        name = b;
    }

    student6(student6 s) {
        id = s.id;
        name = s.name;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(id + "..." + name);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        student6 s1 = new student6(11, "Suresh");
        student6 s2 = new student6(s1);

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the first constructor when the 'id' and 'name' both are set, why the values are not provided to 'i' and 'n' from second constructor.

or is there any way to get 'i' and 'n' gets populated by this way.